# How do I output an addition sequence when using for loop?

Tags: java

I have tried programming recently and there is an exercise online that involves adding the odd integer values of any inputted integer.

My code is able to output the sum of the odd integer values but the exercise asks to output an addition sequence like 1 + 3 + 5... = sum.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int number, oddSumPositive = 0, oddSumNegative = 0;
        
        System.out.print("Enter an integer : ");
        number = input.nextInt();   
        
        oddSumPositive = sumOfOdd_Postive(number);
        oddSumNegative = sumOfOdd_Negative(number);     

        //different scenarios
        if(number > 0) {
            System.out.println("\nThe Sum of Odd Numbers upto " + number + " = " + oddSumPositive);
        }
        else if(number < 0) {
            System.out.println("\nThe Sum of Odd Numbers upto " + number + " = " + oddSumNegative);
        }
        else if(number == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nThe Sum of Odd Numbers upto 0 = 0");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nError");
        }
    }
    
    //Method for positive integers  
        public static int sumOfOdd_Postive(int num)
        {
            int i, sum = 0;
            for(i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                if (i%2 != 0)
                {
                    sum += i;
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }

            
            }
            return sum;
    }   
    //Method for negative integers
        public static int sumOfOdd_Negative(int num) 
        {
            int i, sum = 0;
            for(i = -1; i >= num; i--) 
            {
                if (i%2 != 0) 
                {
                    sum += i;
                    System.out.println((i) + " ");
            
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Comment: could you add  sample input and your current output with expected output

Comment: @rajan.kali 
If the user enters 6.  The output should be  1+3+5= 9.

Comment: You might want to take a look at class `StringBuilder`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Note taken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int sumOfOddPostive(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i%2 != 0) {
            sum += i;
            if (i != 1) {
                System.out.print("+ ");
            }
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("= " + sum);
    // int n = (num + 1)/2; sum = n*n;
    return sum;
}
```

To have a "+" between the terms (one less than the number of terms),
one way is to skip the first (or last term).

It is questionable whether both calculation and output should be so mixed.
Of course the sum can be calculated without all those additions.

Comment: I appreciate this a bunch

Comment: Why does nobody ever check for an odd number with `(n & 1) != 0`?

Comment: @Kaplan Personally i do. But it is a bit of insider's coding,a bit obfuscating the meaning, say in modulo 8.

Comment: Yes, I understand what You mean. But it is insider's coding too, of course, because it's so rarely seen .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not printing `+` as a character anywhere in your code snippet, try below snippet

```
public static int sumOfOdd_Postive(int num) {
      int i, sum = 0;
      for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
          if (i%2 != 0) {
              sum += i;
              System.out.print(i + "");
              if(i != num - 1){ //to avoid + at end of expression
                  System.out.print("+");    
              }
          }
      }
      System.out.print("="+sum);
      return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to avoid the + at the end of the expression.

Comment: glad i could help, please accept and upvote the answer if you think it answered your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have 15 reputations so the website does not publicly display the upvote but I have accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `String` so your method should return a `String`, not an `int`
Also, you can use `StringBuilder` in order to create a concatenated `String`.

Here is a naive implementation :

```
static String sumOdds(int limit) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
        if ( i%2 == 1 ) {
            sum += i;
            sb.append(i);
            if (i + 2 <= limit) {
                sb.append(" + ");
            } else {
                sb.append(" = ").append(sum);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

That being said, as you only want odd or even numbers, there is no point to increment the step one by one and check modulos, you could directly start at 1 and increment steps by 2 :

```
static String sumOdds(int limit) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i+=2) {
        sum += i;
        sb.append(i);
        if (i + 2 <= limit) {
            sb.append(" + ");
        } else {
            sb.append(" = ").append(sum);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Also, later, you will discover... **Streams** !
You can create a **Stream** of **Integer** and use some **Collectors** in order to do fancy things with them.

For example :

```
static IntStream oddStream(int limit) {
    /*
     * Here, you can also generate directly odd numbers without filtering
     * but it is a bit out of scope.
     * See : https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/generate-finite-infinite-stream/
     */
    return IntStream.range(1, limit + 1).filter(i -> i % 2 == 1);
}
```

Then, you can use it to get all the values, map them to a `String` and collect them in a `String`, where the values are separated with `" + "`

```
String str = Main.oddStream(limit)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));
```

Also, you can use the same Stream in order to sum all the values :

```
long sum = Main.oddStream(limit).sum();
```

Which allows you to create the desired result like this :

```
static String sumEven(int limit) {
    String str = Main.oddStream(limit)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));
    long sum = Main.oddStream(limit).sum();
    return str + " = " + sum;
}
```